# Evaluate a symbolic expression inside a MathematicalProgram constraint

Tags: drake

I want to use a symbolic expression as a `MathematicalProgram` constraint but am unsure how to achieve this. My best go so far is the following (simplified example):

```
x = Variable("x")
expression = x**2

prog = MathematicalProgram()
v = prog.NewContinuousVariables(1)
prog.AddConstraint(
    lambda a: Evaluate(np.array([expression]), {x: a[0].value()}),
    lb=np.array([0.0]),
    ub=np.array([0.0]),
    vars=v,
)
result = Solve(prog)
```

I'm getting the error `PyFunctionConstraint: Output must be of scalar type AutoDiffXd. Got float instead.`. Using `lambda a: Evaluate(np.array([expression]), {x: a[0]})` does not work due to incompatible function arguments.

I'd highly appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Hongkai Dai`'s answer with the `ExpressionConstraint` in C++ led me in the right direction. There is such a constraint in `pydrake` (see [here](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.solvers.mathematicalprogram.html?highlight=expressionconstraint#pydrake.solvers.mathematicalprogram.MathematicalProgram.AddConstraint)). However, it currently does not support array inputs. The second required insight was that it is possible to use `prog.NewContinuousVariables` in symbolic expression operations (e.g. `Jacobian`).

Using these insights, I solved my problem with something similar to the following:

```py
prog = MathematicalProgram()
x = prog.NewContinuousVariables(2)
expression = x[0]**2
J = expression.Jacobian([x[0]])
for i in range(2):
  prog.AddConstraint(J[i], 0.0, 0.0)
result = Solve(prog)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we currently support adding symbolic::Expression as constraint in pydrake yet. On the other hand, we do support ExpressionConstraint in C++ version of Drake.

May I ask why you would like to impose the constraint using symbolic Expression? It is generally much faster to evaluate the constraint, if pass a function directly, something like this

```py
def foo(x):
  return np.array([x[0] **2])

prog.AddConstraint(foo, np.array([0.]), np.array([0.]), vars=v)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know! Seems like I'm approaching my problem from the wrong perspective then.

My use case for symbolic expressions is that I want to impose a constraint using the Jacobian of an expression. Taking the Jacobian is easy in pydrake for symbolic expressions but it does not seem to be supported for MathematicalProgram variable expressions. Is it possible to achieve this in pydrake (using symbolic expressions or something else)?